# How can I connect to SUPRA database from a Java application, without the supported JDBC driver

Tags: java, database, jdbc, zos

I want to work supra database and my application is written in Java. I need use tje Java JDBC for connect supra. We use lib and jar file for connect to another database like Mysql and Oracle. Is there a tool or lib to connect supra database?
 - java application running on linux
 - supra database running on zos IBM(mainframe)

What are the steps to do this?

As a further requirement, I do not have a Cincom support contract, and so can't use the normal JDBC driver.  Rather, I need a free or open source JDBC driver.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to the Supra DB using plain JDBC . Refer [this](http://dbsupra.cincom.com/?elqPURLPage=74&elq=00000000000000000000000000000000) for more.

> JDBC 3.0 Driver is a major new release and includes enhancements for:
>
> 1. Support of the JDBC 3.0 API. New supported interfaces are: DataSource,
> 2. ConnectionPoolDataSource, PooledConnection, and ParameterMetaData.
> 3. Support and documentation for running with IBM Websphere
> 4. Use of a single ini file: SupraSQLDriver.ini
> 5. Enhanced tracing and the ability to set call interface trace options
> 6. Standardization of SQLCODEs issued from the JNI layer
> 7. Changed return handling for some methods

Comment: tnx for your answer
To get more detailed information about the JDBC 3.0 Driver, I shoud contact Cincom Support but i need open source or free tools.